# Inject Google and Facebook connection factory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-social

I created SocialConfig which looks like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig {

  //enviroments

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry connectionFactoryRegistry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        connectionFactoryRegistry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookAppId, facebookAppSecret));
        connectionFactoryRegistry.addConnectionFactory(new GoogleConnectionFactory(googleAppId, googleAppSecret));
        return connectionFactoryRegistry;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to inject fb and google connection factory in some services but I getting information that there is not beans. I also tried without `@EnableSocial` but not helping at all. My goal is to get information about user without set app id and secret in services.
To be clear how I inject them:

```java
   private FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory;
    private GoogleConnectionFactory googleConnectionFactory;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public SocialServiceImpl(FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory, GoogleConnectionFactory googleConnectionFactory, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.facebookConnectionFactory = facebookConnectionFactory;
        this.googleConnectionFactory = googleConnectionFactory;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

but getting following error,

> Parameter 0 of constructor in ...SocialServiceImpl required a bean of type '>org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: You've created bean of type `ConnectionFactoryLocator `, not `FacebookConnectionFactory` so there's nothing Spring could inject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not create beans and you should create two beans like that and then Spring can inject these beans to application. Also, you can check [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html) related with bean creation and configuration.

```
@Bean
public FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory() {
    return new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookAppId, facebookAppSecret);
}

@Bean
public GoogleConnectionFactory googleConnectionFactory() {
    return new GoogleConnectionFactory(googleAppId, googleAppSecret);
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry connectionFactoryRegistry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
    connectionFactoryRegistry.addConnectionFactory(facebookConnectionFactory());
    connectionFactoryRegistry.addConnectionFactory(googleConnectionFactory());
    return connectionFactoryRegistry;
}
```